# Substitute Property with Variable Value nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to substitute my property name in a custom way within my insert with nodejs/mongoskin.

```
/* Insert new object */
router.post('/save', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    db.collection('objects').insert(req.body, function(err, result) {
        if (result) {
            var test= "try";
            //insert read and write permissions to Administrator
            db.collection('roles').findAndModify({name:"Administrator"},{_id:1}, {$push:{test: { $each: [ {read:true}, {write:true} ] }}}, function(err, result){
                    res.send(
                        (err === null) ? { msg: '' } : { msg: err });
                })
        }}
    )
});
```

Instead of inserting into an array called `try`, it inserts `test`.

I wish I could substitute the `test` property with my custom variable.

I am new to mongo and node.

Comment: Why not change `test=somethingElse`?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer is to use global variable outside of your code:

```
var test = "try";

/* Insert new object */
router.post('/save', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    db.collection('objects').insert(req.body, function(err, result) {
        if (result) {                 
            //insert read and write permissions to Administrator
            db.collection('roles').findAndModify({name:"Administrator"},{_id:1}, {$push:{test: { $each: [ {read:true}, {write:true} ] }}}, function(err, result){
                    res.send(
                        (err === null) ? { msg: '' } : { msg: err });
                })
        }}
    )
});
```

But it is usually the bad practice.

The other way is to construct callback function using your parameter:

```
var createCallback = function(_property) {
    return function(req, res) {
       var db = req.db;
       db.collection('objects').insert(req.body, function(err, result) {
          if (result) {
            var test = _property;
            //insert read and write permissions to Administrator
            db.collection('roles').findAndModify({name:"Administrator"},{_id:1}, {$push:{test: {                        $each: [ {read:true}, {write:true} ] }}}, function(err, result){
                    res.send(
                        (err === null) ? { msg: '' } : { msg: err });
                });
        }});
    }
}


router.post('/save', createCallback("try"));
```

Comment: None of these worked for me. I am still adding item to the property "test" instead of variable test value.

Comment: @FelipeSoares It is difficult to show you this code working in jsfiddle, since you are using mongo in your snippet...